# Directx11 How to manage multiple vertex/index buffers?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm Working on a small game framework as I am learning DirectX11.
What could be the best method to have a `BufferManager` class (maybe static) to handle all the vertex and index data of the models created both in real time or before. The class should be responsible for creating the Buffers dynamic or static, depending on the model info and then drawing them.

- Should I have one vertex and index vector list and append all the new models to it... and then recreate the buffers, whenever new data is appended and set the new buffers before drawing.
- Should I have seperate vertex and index buffers for the models, access respective model's buffer and set to `IASetVertexBuffer(model[i].getVertBuff())` before each draw call;
- Also some models could be dynamic and others static, how can I do batching here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not showing any code here but the construct that you are requesting would be as follows:

- Create a file loader for, textures, model meshes, vertex data, normal, audio, etc.
- Have a reusable structure that stores all of this data for a particular mesh of a model.
- When creating this you will also want a separate texture class to hold information about different textures. This way the same texture can be referenced for different models or meshes and you won't have to load them into memory each time.
- The same can be done about different meshes; you can reference a mesh that may be a part of different model objects.
- To do this you would need an Asset Storage class that will manage all of your assets. This way if an asset is already in memory it will not load it again; such as a font, a texture, a model, an audio file, etc.
- Then the next part you will need is a Batch class and a Batch Manager class

  - The batch class will define the container of what a batch is based off of a few parameters: Primitive types, if they have transparencies or not (priority queue) etc.
  - The Batch Manager class will do the organization and send the batches to the rendering stage. This class will also be used to state how many vertices a batch can hold and how many batches (buckets) you have. The ratio will depend on the game content. A good ratio for a basic 2D sprite type application would be approximately 10 batches where each batch contains not less than 10,000 vertices. The next step would be then to populate a bucket of similar types based on Primitive Type and its Priority (alpha channel - for Z depth), and if a bucket can not hold the data it will then look for another bucket to fill. If no buckets are available to hold the data, then the Batch Manager will look for the bucket that is most filled with the highest priority queue, it will send that batch to the video card to be rendered, then it will reuse that bucket.
- The last part would be a ShaderManager class to manage different types of shaders that your program will use. So all of these classes or structures will be tied together.

If you design this appropriately you can abstract all of the Engines behaviors and responsibilities away from the actual Game Content, Properties and Logic or set of Rules. This way your Game Engine can be reusable for multiple games. That way your engine doesn't have any dependencies on a particular game and when you are ready to reuse it all you have to do is create a main project that inherits from either this Static or Dynamic library and all of the Engine Components will be incorporated into the next game. This separation of code is an excellent approach for generic reusable code.

For an excellent representation of this approach I would suggest checking out this website [www.MarekKnows.com](http://www.MarekKnows.com) and follow the Shader Engine series of video tutorials. Albeit this particular website focuses on a Win32 in C++ but uses OpenGL instead of DirectX. However the overall design pattern has the same concept. The only difference would be to strip out the OpenGL parts and replace them with the DirectX API.

**EDIT** - Additional References:

- [Geometric Tools](https://www.geometrictools.com/)
- [Rastertek](http://www.rastertek.com/)
- [3D Buzz](http://www.3dbuzz.com/)
- [Learn OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/)
- [GPU Gems by NVidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems/gpugems_pref01.html)
- [Batches PDF by NVidia](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/8228/BatchBatchBatch.pdf)
- [Hieroglyph3 @ Codeplex](https://hieroglyph3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/PipelineManagerDX11.cpp)

I also found this write up on Batch Rendering Process that is by Marek Krzeminski which is from his video tutorials but found here [Batch Rendering by Marek at Gamedev](https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-batch-rendering-r3900)

Comment: Wow!!! u sure know how to make an engine , I understood somewhat (sorry i am new to all this ).Thanks for the link and taking the time to reply with such details.I'll go through your answer multiple times in order to understand it xD.

Comment: @Tesla I've been studying it for quite a while now independently and that is only the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @Tesla I also updated my answer with an edit section with a few more references.

Comment: As a note to future readers I had referenced www.MarekKnows.com within my answer. Now his website currently is no longer available. I'll leave it here for historical purposes since this is where I had learned most of these concepts from. I'm leaving as it to give credit where it is due. However, you can do a search for Marek or MarekKnows on Youtube and find some of his videos there which is only a small portion of his tutorial series. I have the actual videos downloaded to my PC but I can not share them due to copyright reasons. The videos in my collect is earned and paid for content.